# Writing to arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of integers and I want to save pairs of integers using the index of the array as one of the indexes and the value as the other integer.

For example, if I wanted to save the pair: 2, 4. I could do: dependencias[2] = 4 (or dependencias[4] = 2.

It should be fairly simple, right? But I can't do it! I keep getting an out of bounds error. This is my code:

```
int recursoA, recursoB;
dependencias = new int[numberDependencias];
/* I tried setting them all to 0, to see if that was the problem. 
 * It didn't do anything, as I expected. */
for (int i = 0; i < numberDependencias; i++){
    dependencias[i] = 0;
}
int recursoA, recursoB,cont = 0;
while (numberDependencias > 0){
    System.out.println("Introduce el primer recurso");
    recursoA = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    if ((recursoA > 1) && (recursoA <= recursos)){
        System.out.println("Introduce el segundo recurso");
            recursoB = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        dependencias[recursoA] = recursoB; // This is the problem, apparently.
    numberDependencias--;
}
```

Sorry the variables are in Spanish, but hopefully you'll see what I'm talking about. I can't translate it right now.

Comment: What is the value of numberDependencias? Is it more than 4? You are setting a value at array index 4, so it needs to be at least 5.

Comment: what is the value of the variable "recursos"?

Comment: Whoever has to maintain your code will thank you if you consider a solution that doesn't give special meaning to even/odd members of an array.

Comment: numberDependencias is set by the user and in the real code I do check that recursoA and recurso B are [2..numberDependencias] (1 and 0 are not acceptable for this problem).

Comment: @mikidelux!! Your question solved my problem! The array should be dependencias = new int[recursos] Thank you guys, I can't believe I couldn't see that one!

Comment: @KirkWoll I don't think I understand what you're saying about the even/odd members. If it's because it could either be stored as dependencias[2] = 4 or dependencias[4] = 2... well, I guess that's fair.

Comment: @KirkWoll Either I am really confuse or you are, odd numbers don't get a different treatment in this code. I just put an example with only even numbers but you could also store: dependencias[4] = 3

Comment: I suppose I can't understand what you're doing.  I'll leave you alone. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integer you're reading-in (recursoA) has to be greater than 1 and less than "recursos".  The problem, is that "recursos" is probably greater than "numberDependencias"...which is the max size of your array.

Either alter this line to make sure that recursoA is always less then numberDependencias.

```
if ((recursoA > 1) && (recursoA < numberDependencias)){
```

Or, define your array size to be "recursos".

```
dependencias = new int[recursos];
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the error is being caused by the line:

```
if ((recursoA > 1) && (recursoA <= recursos)){
```

What value is `recursos` being set to?  If it is above `numberDependencias` then an out of bounds error would make sense.  Additionally, the open brace at the end of that line doesn't seem to be being closed.  This will certainly cause an error!

Comment: Yes, that was it. I meant to have an array of length recursos, not numberDependencias. As for the braces, I took out a bunch of output code to make it easier to read, that's why it's missing one here.

Answer (score 3):

A Java array has fixed bounds. If you declare it like this:

```
a = new int[3];
```

then you can only assign values to `a[0], a[1] and a[2]`. What you want here is not an array but a [Map.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Map.html)

```
Map<Integer, Integer> dependencias = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
dependencias.put(4000, 2000);

dependencias.get(4000) // returns 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is right here `numberDependencias > 0`, because you initialze an array with number of elements starting at 0. When you start to fill at numberDependencias, you're try to put in an element out of the arrays size. Try `numberDependencias-1 > 0` and use `array[numberDependencias]` instead of recursoA, excepting you want to initialize your array with recursoA.

Instead of an array I would prefer `java.util.HashMap` where you can easily put key-value pairs into, besides that you don't need to worry about initializing your size or out of bounds errors.

Answer (score 0):

What values are you trying to introduce for recursoA?

I think you should check if this value is between 0 and numberDependencias-1. Keep in mind that arrays begin at 0, so if you create an array with 4 positions, you can assign values to array[0] ... array[3].

Answer (score 0):

Well I believe what you're saying that you are creating an array that's the size of the number of these "pairs" you have. However, this will give you out of range errors if you have a number larger then the number of pairs, you will get errors. If this is unclear, say you have 2 pairs, (9, 3) and (3, 4), and you try to save them in your array as  dependencias[3] = 9 and  dependencias[4] = 3. Your going to get errors as  dependencias is not large enough for those values to be used as indexes.

To fix this use a Map, which is made like this,

```
Map<Integer, Integer> dependencias = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

then you can add things to your map, like so:

```
dependencias.put(someInteger1, someInteger2);
```

Finally you can call back that pair using:

```
dependencias.get(someInteger1); //this will return someInteger2
```